# MONGODB How many models are necessary to make a wish list?

Tags: json, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, redux

Okay lets I am making a wish list. You signup/login and you could add products to the list. I am coming from MYSQL so if i was gonna do it in MYSQL I would do this.

table: USERNAME

```
id|username|password
```

table: wishlist

```
id|userid|wish
```

Then I would call the wish list by using the users id. But mongoDB is different because it uses `json`. For the `mongoose` model would I do this?

```
{
username
password
wishlist{
  productname
  bla bla
}
}
```

How would I set this up? I am doing this in react-redux. I have already made something with authentication where you can signup and add/delete wishes but the problem is that all of the products from all of the users are on the same page. Currently I have two separate models for the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how you can do this ( keep in mind you don't have to define id field as mongo will add one automatically ):

-- mongodb.js --

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Connect to database. (replace username, password and dbname).
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/dbname', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    autoIndex: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to mongodb...'))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

// Define user schema.
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    index: true
  },
  password: String
});

// Define virtual field ( it "connects" two collections ( collections are like tables in MYSQL ) ).
UserSchema.virtual('wishlists', {
  ref: 'Wishlists',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'userid'
}, {
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true
  },
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true
  }
});

// Define wishlist schema with field "userid" that references a user in "Users" collection.
const WishlistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userid: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Users'
  },
  wish: String
});

// Create collections called "Users" and "Wishlists" and export for use.
module.exports = {
  User: mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema),
  Wishlist: mongoose.model('Wishlists', WishlistSchema)
};
```

And then you can use this in your NodeJS server ( your API ) using these lines as examples:

```js
const Models = require('./mongodb.js');
const User = Models.User;
const Wishlist = Models.Wishlist;

// Add new.
await new User({
  name: name,
  password: password
}).save();

// Find user by id.
await Users.findById('someid')
  .select();

// Find wishlists by userid and find user ( but keep out password! ).
await Wishlist.find({
  userid: 'someid'
}).select().populate('userid', 'username');

// Find user and all wishlists associated (using virtual fields from mongodb ).
await Users.findById('someid')
  .select().populate('wishlists');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to mongoDB. This is very helpful.